# Tomcat JDBC Thin driver SSL Oracle Wallet, NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSO KeyStore not available

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

We are trying to connect to Oracle 19C Database from our spring based web application deployed on tomcat (version 8.5.81) which uses java version 1.8_17. This is JDBC Thin Connectivity. We are able to connect to the DB from the same server via putty outside the Tomcat Server by writing a TEST Connection Program. But via Tomcat it is not working.

Below are the steps that were carried out

1. SSL Certificates of DB installed and present in the Oracle cwallet : Below is the location
2. Added below 4 jars into Tomcat and Oracle Client lib folder. Gave permissions to these jars
3. Added these jars into CLASSPATH
4. Added -D parameters (highlighted in bold ) in Tomcat catalina.sh

   ```
   eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
     -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
     -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
   ```

   **-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/data/oraclt/product/clt19.4.0.0/network/admin/wallet/cwallet.sso"" 

   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=""SSO"" 

   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=""/data/oraclt/product/clt19.4.0.0/network/admin/wallet/cwallet.sso"" 

   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=""SSO"" 

   -Doracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=false 

   -Doracle.net.ssl_version=1.2 **
   -Dcatalina.base=""$CATALINA_BASE"" 
   -Dcatalina.home=""$CATALINA_HOME"" 
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=""$CATALINA_TMPDIR"" 
   **-Doracle.net.wallet_location=""(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/data/oraclt/product/clt19.4.0.0/network/admin/wallet/)))"" **
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start 
   >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

Comment: What error are you actually getting? SSH and JDBC are completely different protocols and network ports, so just saying that SSH works and JDBC doesn't really doesn't clarify anything. With what you've provided we can't tell if this is a configuration issue, a firewall issue, a database server issue, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

**Application connectivity to 19c Database**

Tomcat Version : apache-tomcat-8.5.81
JAVA Version : JDK_1.8.0_171

1. Place below files at <TOMCAT_HOME>/lib/ location and give executable permission to all jar files.
   ojdbc8.jar, oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar

At JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security file please add entry highlighted in link
(Reference link : https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc-tlsv12-jks-or-oracle-wallets-122-and-lower#Wallets)

At <tomcat_home>/bin/catalina.sh add ojdbc8.jar, oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar at classpath as shown below
[image]
Also add certificate path as highlighted in below screenshot.
[image]